# Spring and JSF and JPA

Tags: spring, jsf

I'm integrating these in a basic web application, being deployed in Glassfish.
Upon startup, the error I am getting is:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)
```

The closest solution I can find has something to do with asm.jar and cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar.
I added these jars and still got the error. Then I deleted asm.jar only, and still got the error.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like either you have a wrong version of asm.jar somewhere in your classpath or you have some other class depends on asm.jar that's different with the one bundled with cglib-nodep.jar.
Try replacing it with regular cglib.jar and its dependencies (including asm.jar) packaged separately.